# view.getTop() is giving me wrong coordinate

Tags: android, canvas, android-view

I have an xml with a linearLayout that doesn't cover the whole screen.
I took control of it in the mainActivity and sent it to another class:

```
        GameView gv;
        setContentView(R.layout.game_view);
        LinearLayout surface = new LinearLayout(this);
        surface = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.surface);
        gv= new GameView(this,surface);
        surface.addView(gv);
```

at the class GameView i get the context and the linearlayout:

```
public GameView(Context context,LinearLayout view)
```

then i use the functions `getLeft()`,`getTop()`,`getRight()`,`getBottom()`
to draw a big rect on all over the `layout`:

```
        Paint p=new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRect(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom(),p);
```

the `getLeft()` and `getRight()` work perfectly, but the `getTop()` and `getBottom()` are offset of about 6 pxs;

I have no idea of why this happens